# How to enable/disable button based on user edit access in LWC datatable?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, security, lwc-wire-adapter, datatable

I am building a Lightning Web Component (LWC) that retrieves data from Apex and displays it in a datatable. Currently, the LWC component retrieves all records from Apex, but I want to fetch that the user has edit access and read only access sepratly. I also want to add a button to a column in the datatable that will update the status of the record, but the button should only be clickable for users who have edit access to the record. For read-only users, the button should be disabled.

How can I achieve this in my LWC? What is the best way to filter the records based on the user's edit access, and how can I conditionally enable/disable the button based on the user's permissions? Any sample code or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved via the uiRecordAPI getRecords wire adapter. That adapter allows you to retrieve a batch of records at once, and then use the returned records in your component. To provide the disabling of the button based off the user's permission, you'll need to include the following field in your fields list within the wire service:

```
@salesforce/schema/object__c.UserRecordAccess.HasEditAccess
```

This can be access via

```
wiredObject.data.fields.UserRecordAccess.value.fields.HasEditAccess
```

References:

- getRecords Adapter: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_records
- UserRecordAccess field: [Can I use wire service to get data from UserRecordAccess and use it in LWC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/334026/can-i-use-wire-service-to-get-data-from-userrecordaccess-and-use-it-in-lwc)

Comment: I am using apex to get data, is there any other way which give me edit and read only records separately.